Rank analysis of a random binary matrix within a random binary matrix
Let's say we have a matrix $A \in \mathbb{R}^{m, n}$ which is a random binary matrix where each entry draws from the Bernoulli distribution with $P(n=1) = p_a$ and $P(n=0) = 1 - p_a$.
Similarly, we have a smaller matrix $B \in \mathbb{R}^{o, p}$ ($o < m$ and $p < n$) which is a random binary matrix where each entry draws from a different Bernoulli distribution with $P(n=1) = p_b$ and $P(n=0) = 1 - p_b$.
We "put" matrix $B$ inside matrix $A$ at some location (it can be the center of $A$, the top-left corner, etc), specifically by overwriting all of the $A$ entries with $B$ entries in the corresponding location. Let us call this new matrix $C$. So matrix $C$ looks like this:
$$C = \begin{bmatrix} A^\prime_{0, 0} & A^\prime_{0, 1} & A^\prime_{0, 2} \\\ A^\prime_{1, 0} & B & A^\prime_{1, 2} \\\ A^\prime_{2, 0} & A^\prime_{2, 1} & A^\prime_{2, 2} \end{bmatrix}$$
where $A^\prime_{x, y}$ is some sub-matrix of $A$.
We are given the following properties:

$P(A\text{ is non-singular}) = \sigma_A$
$P(B\text{ is non-singular}) = \sigma_B$
$\mathbb{E}\left[\text{rank}(A)\right] = \delta_A$
$\mathbb{E}\left[\text{rank}(B)\right] = \delta_B$.

The main questions are:

What is $P(C\text{ is non-singular})$?
What is $\mathbb{E}\left[\text{rank}(C)\right]$?

I think this is a difficult problem to prove, but if anyone can point me in the right direction on research papers to read, that will also be greatly appreciated!
